# Markdown cross-reference anchors with Ascii and CJK characters

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

On GitHub, I have a markdown section title that mixes English and CJK characters like this:

```
## English中文标题
```

Then I try to create the corresponding table of content item like this

```
[English中文标题](#English中文标题)
```

However, this one gets interpreted as html link but does not link me to the section title.

A pure English or pure CJK section title works fine.

I tried adding a white space between the English and the first CJK character in the title, then added a dash in-between. This doesn't create the right link either:

```
[English 中文标题](#English-中文标题)
```

I noticed that the auto-generated section anchor by GitHub uses the CJK characters, instead of the html character code, for the anchor link.

Comment: Which part of GitHub are you using? I just tried a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/waylan/833c3cd8e61cd1b96fd750a5a0a5b224) and it appears to work fine.

Comment: Also, different Markdown implementations behave differently. There is quite [a lot of variance](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%23%23+English%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98%0A%0A%5BEnglish%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98%5D(%23English%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98)%0A%0A%23%23+English%0A%0A%5BEnglish%5D(%23English)%0A%0A%23%23+%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98%0A%0A%5B%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98%5D(%23%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98)). This is a non-standard feature and there is no clear spec to define how it should behave.